# How to replace values with Names in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes
One with a list of names like

```
      Names
1     Apple
2     Banana
3     Peach
```

I have Another dataFrame which has a value that corresponds with a number

```
    Num Value          
1   1   10
2   2   15
3   3   20
```

The Numbers column in the second dataframe should match with the names column in the first dataframe

should look something like this:

```
    Num    Value          
1   apple  10
2   banana 15
3   peach  20
```

I have tried functions like merge() and bind() but I don't think I quite have the result I am looking for and am looking for second opinions.
I am quite new to R so help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have a dataset or table that has both the numeric variable and label?

Comment: df1$Num <- df2$Names

Comment: df1$Num <- df2$Names this worked! Thank you very much!